# How to type math sign for neighbourhood in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

Can you help me please, how to type the sign that is emphasized? It looks like mirror image of sign `\partial`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE....that symbol not correspond to partial but to the calligraphic O.

Answer (score 2):

For example using `mathrsfs` package give to you the symbol `O`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{O}$
\end{document}
```